# How do I see my developed android app stacktrace on my phone or laptop?

Tags: android

So, background. I had a htc desire 616 which I was using to test my apps. I connected it to my PC and immediately got the notification that would allow my device to always be used when developing. Now I don't have that device.
I got a Samsung j1 2016 that I'm trying to use now but I have gone through soo many questions on here to try and make my device go from offline to device when I execute
   adb devices
on the command line and none have worked.
The only reason I would use adb is to see the stack trace on the android studio which I then use to debug.
So after fighting with my adb and updating and doing mini hacks using answers I find here. I've decided to let adb go completely.

So the question is, how do I EASILY see the stack trace of an app I'm debugging on my android device from either the device itself or using a desktop application so that I can get back to debugging??

I just tried installing catalog and apparently it can only see its own logs .
I'd like to do all this without rooting the device, please.
I have a Mac running OS X 10.6.8.

Thanks.

Comment: any program that can do this will use adb under the hood. Sounds like you just need the correct drives to make it work

Comment: That's bad news .

Comment: Isn't there some way I can detect a program crash and print the stacktrace to an activity that I then look at? Or a way to send the stacktrace into a file again, from the app??